# Apache virtual host for TLD wildcard

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost, tld

I am trying to make a named Virtual Host that redirects all TLDs to my .com VirtualHost.  I can't seem to make a wildcard work for the ServerName directive, and I haven't been able to figure this one out.

I realize I can do this easily with RewriteRules, but that's a more expensive solution that I would prefer to avoid.

I have my normal site vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/myfiles
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to create a VirtualHost that redirects all TLDs to that one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName .mydomain.*
    ServerAlias mydomain.*
    Redirect / http://www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

However that does not seem to work.  Requests to www.mydomain.it do not match this vhost, and end up being sent to my default vhost.

Can someone tell me the "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make this work on Apache 2.2.15 by using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.* www.example.*
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to make this work by simply enumerating all of the ICANN TLDs.  I'm not sure what the performance of this is, so I'm still looking for a wildcard catch-all solution.

That said, this should work. (May require significant scrolling to the right!)

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
  # Catch-all VHost for non .com TLDs
  ServerName *.mydomain.tld

  ServerAlias *.mydomain.ac *.mydomain.academy *.mydomain.accountants *.mydomain.actor *.mydomain.ad *.mydomain.ae *.mydomain.aero *.mydomain.af *.mydomain.ag *.mydomain.agency *.mydomain.ai *.mydomain.airforce *.mydomain.al *.mydomain.am *.mydomain.an *.mydomain.ao *.mydomain.aq *.mydomain.ar *.mydomain.archi *.mydomain.arpa *.mydomain.as *.mydomain.asia *.mydomain.associates *.mydomain.at *.mydomain.au *.mydomain.audio *.mydomain.aw *.mydomain.ax *.mydomain.axa *.mydomain.az *.mydomain.ba *.mydomain.bar *.mydomain.bargains *.mydomain.bayern *.mydomain.bb *.mydomain.bd *.mydomain.be *.mydomain.beer *.mydomain.berlin *.mydomain.best *.mydomain.bf *.mydomain.bg *.mydomain.bh *.mydomain.bi *.mydomain.bid *.mydomain.bike *.mydomain.biz *.mydomain.bj *.mydomain.black *.mydomain.blackfriday *.mydomain.blue *.mydomain.bm *.mydomain.bn *.mydomain.bo *.mydomain.boutique *.mydomain.br *.mydomain.bs *.mydomain.bt *.mydomain.build *.mydomain.builders *.mydomain.buzz *.mydomain.bv *.mydomain.bw *.mydomain.by *.mydomain.bz *.mydomain.ca *.mydomain.cab *.mydomain.camera *.mydomain.camp *.mydomain.capital *.mydomain.cards *.mydomain.care *.mydomain.career *.mydomain.careers *.mydomain.cash *.mydomain.cat *.mydomain.catering *.mydomain.cc *.mydomain.cd *.mydomain.center *.mydomain.ceo *.mydomain.cf *.mydomain.cg *.mydomain.ch *.mydomain.cheap *.mydomain.christmas *.mydomain.church *.mydomain.ci *.mydomain.citic *.mydomain.ck *.mydomain.cl *.mydomain.claims *.mydomain.cleaning *.mydomain.clinic *.mydomain.clothing *.mydomain.club *.mydomain.cm *.mydomain.cn *.mydomain.co *.mydomain.codes *.mydomain.coffee *.mydomain.college *.mydomain.cologne *.mydomain.community *.mydomain.company *.mydomain.computer *.mydomain.condos *.mydomain.construction *.mydomain.consulting *.mydomain.contractors *.mydomain.cooking *.mydomain.cool *.mydomain.coop *.mydomain.country *.mydomain.cr *.mydomain.credit *.mydomain.creditcard *.mydomain.cruises *.mydomain.cu *.mydomain.cv *.mydomain.cw *.mydomain.cx *.mydomain.cy *.mydomain.cz *.mydomain.dance *.mydomain.dating *.mydomain.de *.mydomain.democrat *.mydomain.dental *.mydomain.desi *.mydomain.diamonds *.mydomain.digital *.mydomain.directory *.mydomain.discount *.mydomain.dj *.mydomain.dk *.mydomain.dm *.mydomain.dnp *.mydomain.do *.mydomain.domains *.mydomain.dz *.mydomain.ec *.mydomain.edu *.mydomain.education *.mydomain.ee *.mydomain.eg *.mydomain.email *.mydomain.engineering *.mydomain.enterprises *.mydomain.equipment *.mydomain.er *.mydomain.es *.mydomain.estate *.mydomain.et *.mydomain.eu *.mydomain.eus *.mydomain.events *.mydomain.exchange *.mydomain.expert *.mydomain.exposed *.mydomain.fail *.mydomain.farm *.mydomain.feedback *.mydomain.fi *.mydomain.finance *.mydomain.financial *.mydomain.fish *.mydomain.fishing *.mydomain.fitness *.mydomain.fj *.mydomain.fk *.mydomain.flights *.mydomain.florist *.mydomain.fm *.mydomain.fo *.mydomain.foo *.mydomain.foundation *.mydomain.fr *.mydomain.frogans *.mydomain.fund *.mydomain.furniture *.mydomain.futbol *.mydomain.ga *.mydomain.gal *.mydomain.gallery *.mydomain.gb *.mydomain.gd *.mydomain.ge *.mydomain.gf *.mydomain.gg *.mydomain.gh *.mydomain.gi *.mydomain.gift *.mydomain.gl *.mydomain.glass *.mydomain.globo *.mydomain.gm *.mydomain.gmo *.mydomain.gn *.mydomain.gop *.mydomain.gov *.mydomain.gp *.mydomain.gq *.mydomain.gr *.mydomain.graphics *.mydomain.gratis *.mydomain.gripe *.mydomain.gs *.mydomain.gt *.mydomain.gu *.mydomain.guide *.mydomain.guitars *.mydomain.guru *.mydomain.gw *.mydomain.gy *.mydomain.haus *.mydomain.hiphop *.mydomain.hk *.mydomain.hm *.mydomain.hn *.mydomain.holdings *.mydomain.holiday *.mydomain.horse *.mydomain.house *.mydomain.hr *.mydomain.ht *.mydomain.hu *.mydomain.id *.mydomain.ie *.mydomain.il *.mydomain.im *.mydomain.immobilien *.mydomain.in *.mydomain.industries *.mydomain.info *.mydomain.ink *.mydomain.institute *.mydomain.insure *.mydomain.int *.mydomain.international *.mydomain.investments *.mydomain.io *.mydomain.iq *.mydomain.ir *.mydomain.is *.mydomain.it *.mydomain.je *.mydomain.jetzt *.mydomain.jm *.mydomain.jo *.mydomain.jobs *.mydomain.jp *.mydomain.juegos *.mydomain.kaufen *.mydomain.ke *.mydomain.kg *.mydomain.kh *.mydomain.ki *.mydomain.kim *.mydomain.kitchen *.mydomain.kiwi *.mydomain.km *.mydomain.kn *.mydomain.koeln *.mydomain.kp *.mydomain.kr *.mydomain.kred *.mydomain.kw *.mydomain.ky *.mydomain.kz *.mydomain.la *.mydomain.land *.mydomain.lb *.mydomain.lc *.mydomain.lease *.mydomain.li *.mydomain.life *.mydomain.lighting *.mydomain.limited *.mydomain.limo *.mydomain.link *.mydomain.lk *.mydomain.loans *.mydomain.london *.mydomain.lr *.mydomain.ls *.mydomain.lt *.mydomain.lu *.mydomain.luxe *.mydomain.luxury *.mydomain.lv *.mydomain.ly *.mydomain.ma *.mydomain.maison *.mydomain.management *.mydomain.mango *.mydomain.marketing *.mydomain.mc *.mydomain.md *.mydomain.me *.mydomain.media *.mydomain.meet *.mydomain.menu *.mydomain.mg *.mydomain.mh *.mydomain.miami *.mydomain.mil *.mydomain.mk *.mydomain.ml *.mydomain.mm *.mydomain.mn *.mydomain.mo *.mydomain.mobi *.mydomain.moda *.mydomain.moe *.mydomain.monash *.mydomain.moscow *.mydomain.mp *.mydomain.mq *.mydomain.mr *.mydomain.ms *.mydomain.mt *.mydomain.mu *.mydomain.museum *.mydomain.mv *.mydomain.mw *.mydomain.mx *.mydomain.my *.mydomain.mz *.mydomain.na *.mydomain.nagoya *.mydomain.name *.mydomain.nc *.mydomain.ne *.mydomain.net *.mydomain.neustar *.mydomain.nf *.mydomain.ng *.mydomain.ni *.mydomain.ninja *.mydomain.nl *.mydomain.no *.mydomain.np *.mydomain.nr *.mydomain.nu *.mydomain.nyc *.mydomain.nz *.mydomain.okinawa *.mydomain.om *.mydomain.onl *.mydomain.org *.mydomain.pa *.mydomain.paris *.mydomain.partners *.mydomain.parts *.mydomain.pe *.mydomain.pf *.mydomain.pg *.mydomain.ph *.mydomain.photo *.mydomain.photography *.mydomain.photos *.mydomain.pics *.mydomain.pictures *.mydomain.pink *.mydomain.pk *.mydomain.pl *.mydomain.plumbing *.mydomain.pm *.mydomain.pn *.mydomain.post *.mydomain.pr *.mydomain.pro *.mydomain.productions *.mydomain.properties *.mydomain.ps *.mydomain.pt *.mydomain.pub *.mydomain.pw *.mydomain.py *.mydomain.qa *.mydomain.qpon *.mydomain.quebec *.mydomain.re *.mydomain.recipes *.mydomain.red *.mydomain.reisen *.mydomain.ren *.mydomain.rentals *.mydomain.repair *.mydomain.report *.mydomain.rest *.mydomain.reviews *.mydomain.rich *.mydomain.ro *.mydomain.rocks *.mydomain.rodeo *.mydomain.rs *.mydomain.ru *.mydomain.ruhr *.mydomain.rw *.mydomain.ryukyu *.mydomain.sa *.mydomain.saarland *.mydomain.sb *.mydomain.sc *.mydomain.schule *.mydomain.sd *.mydomain.se *.mydomain.services *.mydomain.sexy *.mydomain.sg *.mydomain.sh *.mydomain.shiksha *.mydomain.shoes *.mydomain.si *.mydomain.singles *.mydomain.sj *.mydomain.sk *.mydomain.sl *.mydomain.sm *.mydomain.sn *.mydomain.so *.mydomain.social *.mydomain.sohu *.mydomain.solar *.mydomain.solutions *.mydomain.soy *.mydomain.sr *.mydomain.st *.mydomain.su *.mydomain.supplies *.mydomain.supply *.mydomain.support *.mydomain.surgery *.mydomain.sv *.mydomain.sx *.mydomain.sy *.mydomain.systems *.mydomain.sz *.mydomain.tattoo *.mydomain.tax *.mydomain.tc *.mydomain.td *.mydomain.technology *.mydomain.tel *.mydomain.tf *.mydomain.tg *.mydomain.th *.mydomain.tienda *.mydomain.tips *.mydomain.tj *.mydomain.tk *.mydomain.tl *.mydomain.tm *.mydomain.tn *.mydomain.to *.mydomain.today *.mydomain.tokyo *.mydomain.tools *.mydomain.town *.mydomain.toys *.mydomain.tp *.mydomain.tr *.mydomain.trade *.mydomain.training *.mydomain.travel *.mydomain.tt *.mydomain.tv *.mydomain.tw *.mydomain.tz *.mydomain.ua *.mydomain.ug *.mydomain.uk *.mydomain.university *.mydomain.uno *.mydomain.us *.mydomain.uy *.mydomain.uz *.mydomain.va *.mydomain.vacations *.mydomain.vc *.mydomain.ve *.mydomain.vegas *.mydomain.ventures *.mydomain.vg *.mydomain.vi *.mydomain.viajes *.mydomain.villas *.mydomain.vision *.mydomain.vn *.mydomain.vodka *.mydomain.vote *.mydomain.voting *.mydomain.voto *.mydomain.voyage *.mydomain.vu *.mydomain.wang *.mydomain.watch *.mydomain.webcam *.mydomain.wed *.mydomain.wf *.mydomain.wien *.mydomain.wiki *.mydomain.works *.mydomain.ws *.mydomain.wtc *.mydomain.wtf *.mydomain.xn--3bst00m *.mydomain.xn--3ds443g *.mydomain.xn--3e0b707e *.mydomain.xn--45brj9c *.mydomain.xn--55qw42g *.mydomain.xn--55qx5d *.mydomain.xn--6frz82g *.mydomain.xn--6qq986b3xl *.mydomain.xn--80adxhks *.mydomain.xn--80ao21a *.mydomain.xn--80asehdb *.mydomain.xn--80aswg *.mydomain.xn--90a3ac *.mydomain.xn--c1avg *.mydomain.xn--cg4bki *.mydomain.xn--clchc0ea0b2g2a9gcd *.mydomain.xn--czru2d *.mydomain.xn--d1acj3b *.mydomain.xn--fiq228c5hs *.mydomain.xn--fiq64b *.mydomain.xn--fiqs8s *.mydomain.xn--fiqz9s *.mydomain.xn--fpcrj9c3d *.mydomain.xn--fzc2c9e2c *.mydomain.xn--gecrj9c *.mydomain.xn--h2brj9c *.mydomain.xn--i1b6b1a6a2e *.mydomain.xn--io0a7i *.mydomain.xn--j1amh *.mydomain.xn--j6w193g *.mydomain.xn--kprw13d *.mydomain.xn--kpry57d *.mydomain.xn--l1acc *.mydomain.xn--lgbbat1ad8j *.mydomain.xn--mgb9awbf *.mydomain.xn--mgba3a4f16a *.mydomain.xn--mgbaam7a8h *.mydomain.xn--mgbab2bd *.mydomain.xn--mgbayh7gpa *.mydomain.xn--mgbbh1a71e *.mydomain.xn--mgbc0a9azcg *.mydomain.xn--mgberp4a5d4ar *.mydomain.xn--mgbx4cd0ab *.mydomain.xn--ngbc5azd *.mydomain.xn--nqv7f *.mydomain.xn--nqv7fs00ema *.mydomain.xn--o3cw4h *.mydomain.xn--ogbpf8fl *.mydomain.xn--p1ai *.mydomain.xn--pgbs0dh *.mydomain.xn--q9jyb4c *.mydomain.xn--rhqv96g *.mydomain.xn--s9brj9c *.mydomain.xn--ses554g *.mydomain.xn--unup4y *.mydomain.xn--wgbh1c *.mydomain.xn--wgbl6a *.mydomain.xn--xkc2al3hye2a *.mydomain.xn--xkc2dl3a5ee0h *.mydomain.xn--yfro4i67o *.mydomain.xn--ygbi2ammx *.mydomain.xn--zfr164b *.mydomain.xxx *.mydomain.xyz *.mydomain.ye *.mydomain.yokohama *.mydomain.yt *.mydomain.za *.mydomain.zm *.mydomain.zone *.mydomain.zw

  ServerAlias mydomain.ac mydomain.academy mydomain.accountants mydomain.actor mydomain.ad mydomain.ae mydomain.aero mydomain.af mydomain.ag mydomain.agency mydomain.ai mydomain.airforce mydomain.al mydomain.am mydomain.an mydomain.ao mydomain.aq mydomain.ar mydomain.archi mydomain.arpa mydomain.as mydomain.asia mydomain.associates mydomain.at mydomain.au mydomain.audio mydomain.aw mydomain.ax mydomain.axa mydomain.az mydomain.ba mydomain.bar mydomain.bargains mydomain.bayern mydomain.bb mydomain.bd mydomain.be mydomain.beer mydomain.berlin mydomain.best mydomain.bf mydomain.bg mydomain.bh mydomain.bi mydomain.bid mydomain.bike mydomain.biz mydomain.bj mydomain.black mydomain.blackfriday mydomain.blue mydomain.bm mydomain.bn mydomain.bo mydomain.boutique mydomain.br mydomain.bs mydomain.bt mydomain.build mydomain.builders mydomain.buzz mydomain.bv mydomain.bw mydomain.by mydomain.bz mydomain.ca mydomain.cab mydomain.camera mydomain.camp mydomain.capital mydomain.cards mydomain.care mydomain.career mydomain.careers mydomain.cash mydomain.cat mydomain.catering mydomain.cc mydomain.cd mydomain.center mydomain.ceo mydomain.cf mydomain.cg mydomain.ch mydomain.cheap mydomain.christmas mydomain.church mydomain.ci mydomain.citic mydomain.ck mydomain.cl mydomain.claims mydomain.cleaning mydomain.clinic mydomain.clothing mydomain.club mydomain.cm mydomain.cn mydomain.co mydomain.codes mydomain.coffee mydomain.college mydomain.cologne mydomain.community mydomain.company mydomain.computer mydomain.condos mydomain.construction mydomain.consulting mydomain.contractors mydomain.cooking mydomain.cool mydomain.coop mydomain.country mydomain.cr mydomain.credit mydomain.creditcard mydomain.cruises mydomain.cu mydomain.cv mydomain.cw mydomain.cx mydomain.cy mydomain.cz mydomain.dance mydomain.dating mydomain.de mydomain.democrat mydomain.dental mydomain.desi mydomain.diamonds mydomain.digital mydomain.directory mydomain.discount mydomain.dj mydomain.dk mydomain.dm mydomain.dnp mydomain.do mydomain.domains mydomain.dz mydomain.ec mydomain.edu mydomain.education mydomain.ee mydomain.eg mydomain.email mydomain.engineering mydomain.enterprises mydomain.equipment mydomain.er mydomain.es mydomain.estate mydomain.et mydomain.eu mydomain.eus mydomain.events mydomain.exchange mydomain.expert mydomain.exposed mydomain.fail mydomain.farm mydomain.feedback mydomain.fi mydomain.finance mydomain.financial mydomain.fish mydomain.fishing mydomain.fitness mydomain.fj mydomain.fk mydomain.flights mydomain.florist mydomain.fm mydomain.fo mydomain.foo mydomain.foundation mydomain.fr mydomain.frogans mydomain.fund mydomain.furniture mydomain.futbol mydomain.ga mydomain.gal mydomain.gallery mydomain.gb mydomain.gd mydomain.ge mydomain.gf mydomain.gg mydomain.gh mydomain.gi mydomain.gift mydomain.gl mydomain.glass mydomain.globo mydomain.gm mydomain.gmo mydomain.gn mydomain.gop mydomain.gov mydomain.gp mydomain.gq mydomain.gr mydomain.graphics mydomain.gratis mydomain.gripe mydomain.gs mydomain.gt mydomain.gu mydomain.guide mydomain.guitars mydomain.guru mydomain.gw mydomain.gy mydomain.haus mydomain.hiphop mydomain.hk mydomain.hm mydomain.hn mydomain.holdings mydomain.holiday mydomain.horse mydomain.house mydomain.hr mydomain.ht mydomain.hu mydomain.id mydomain.ie mydomain.il mydomain.im mydomain.immobilien mydomain.in mydomain.industries mydomain.info mydomain.ink mydomain.institute mydomain.insure mydomain.int mydomain.international mydomain.investments mydomain.io mydomain.iq mydomain.ir mydomain.is mydomain.it mydomain.je mydomain.jetzt mydomain.jm mydomain.jo mydomain.jobs mydomain.jp mydomain.juegos mydomain.kaufen mydomain.ke mydomain.kg mydomain.kh mydomain.ki mydomain.kim mydomain.kitchen mydomain.kiwi mydomain.km mydomain.kn mydomain.koeln mydomain.kp mydomain.kr mydomain.kred mydomain.kw mydomain.ky mydomain.kz mydomain.la mydomain.land mydomain.lb mydomain.lc mydomain.lease mydomain.li mydomain.life mydomain.lighting mydomain.limited mydomain.limo mydomain.link mydomain.lk mydomain.loans mydomain.london mydomain.lr mydomain.ls mydomain.lt mydomain.lu mydomain.luxe mydomain.luxury mydomain.lv mydomain.ly mydomain.ma mydomain.maison mydomain.management mydomain.mango mydomain.marketing mydomain.mc mydomain.md mydomain.me mydomain.media mydomain.meet mydomain.menu mydomain.mg mydomain.mh mydomain.miami mydomain.mil mydomain.mk mydomain.ml mydomain.mm mydomain.mn mydomain.mo mydomain.mobi mydomain.moda mydomain.moe mydomain.monash mydomain.moscow mydomain.mp mydomain.mq mydomain.mr mydomain.ms mydomain.mt mydomain.mu mydomain.museum mydomain.mv mydomain.mw mydomain.mx mydomain.my mydomain.mz mydomain.na mydomain.nagoya mydomain.name mydomain.nc mydomain.ne mydomain.net mydomain.neustar mydomain.nf mydomain.ng mydomain.ni mydomain.ninja mydomain.nl mydomain.no mydomain.np mydomain.nr mydomain.nu mydomain.nyc mydomain.nz mydomain.okinawa mydomain.om mydomain.onl mydomain.org mydomain.pa mydomain.paris mydomain.partners mydomain.parts mydomain.pe mydomain.pf mydomain.pg mydomain.ph mydomain.photo mydomain.photography mydomain.photos mydomain.pics mydomain.pictures mydomain.pink mydomain.pk mydomain.pl mydomain.plumbing mydomain.pm mydomain.pn mydomain.post mydomain.pr mydomain.pro mydomain.productions mydomain.properties mydomain.ps mydomain.pt mydomain.pub mydomain.pw mydomain.py mydomain.qa mydomain.qpon mydomain.quebec mydomain.re mydomain.recipes mydomain.red mydomain.reisen mydomain.ren mydomain.rentals mydomain.repair mydomain.report mydomain.rest mydomain.reviews mydomain.rich mydomain.ro mydomain.rocks mydomain.rodeo mydomain.rs mydomain.ru mydomain.ruhr mydomain.rw mydomain.ryukyu mydomain.sa mydomain.saarland mydomain.sb mydomain.sc mydomain.schule mydomain.sd mydomain.se mydomain.services mydomain.sexy mydomain.sg mydomain.sh mydomain.shiksha mydomain.shoes mydomain.si mydomain.singles mydomain.sj mydomain.sk mydomain.sl mydomain.sm mydomain.sn mydomain.so mydomain.social mydomain.sohu mydomain.solar mydomain.solutions mydomain.soy mydomain.sr mydomain.st mydomain.su mydomain.supplies mydomain.supply mydomain.support mydomain.surgery mydomain.sv mydomain.sx mydomain.sy mydomain.systems mydomain.sz mydomain.tattoo mydomain.tax mydomain.tc mydomain.td mydomain.technology mydomain.tel mydomain.tf mydomain.tg mydomain.th mydomain.tienda mydomain.tips mydomain.tj mydomain.tk mydomain.tl mydomain.tm mydomain.tn mydomain.to mydomain.today mydomain.tokyo mydomain.tools mydomain.town mydomain.toys mydomain.tp mydomain.tr mydomain.trade mydomain.training mydomain.travel mydomain.tt mydomain.tv mydomain.tw mydomain.tz mydomain.ua mydomain.ug mydomain.uk mydomain.university mydomain.uno mydomain.us mydomain.uy mydomain.uz mydomain.va mydomain.vacations mydomain.vc mydomain.ve mydomain.vegas mydomain.ventures mydomain.vg mydomain.vi mydomain.viajes mydomain.villas mydomain.vision mydomain.vn mydomain.vodka mydomain.vote mydomain.voting mydomain.voto mydomain.voyage mydomain.vu mydomain.wang mydomain.watch mydomain.webcam mydomain.wed mydomain.wf mydomain.wien mydomain.wiki mydomain.works mydomain.ws mydomain.wtc mydomain.wtf mydomain.xn--3bst00m mydomain.xn--3ds443g mydomain.xn--3e0b707e mydomain.xn--45brj9c mydomain.xn--55qw42g mydomain.xn--55qx5d mydomain.xn--6frz82g mydomain.xn--6qq986b3xl mydomain.xn--80adxhks mydomain.xn--80ao21a mydomain.xn--80asehdb mydomain.xn--80aswg mydomain.xn--90a3ac mydomain.xn--c1avg mydomain.xn--cg4bki mydomain.xn--clchc0ea0b2g2a9gcd mydomain.xn--czru2d mydomain.xn--d1acj3b mydomain.xn--fiq228c5hs mydomain.xn--fiq64b mydomain.xn--fiqs8s mydomain.xn--fiqz9s mydomain.xn--fpcrj9c3d mydomain.xn--fzc2c9e2c mydomain.xn--gecrj9c mydomain.xn--h2brj9c mydomain.xn--i1b6b1a6a2e mydomain.xn--io0a7i mydomain.xn--j1amh mydomain.xn--j6w193g mydomain.xn--kprw13d mydomain.xn--kpry57d mydomain.xn--l1acc mydomain.xn--lgbbat1ad8j mydomain.xn--mgb9awbf mydomain.xn--mgba3a4f16a mydomain.xn--mgbaam7a8h mydomain.xn--mgbab2bd mydomain.xn--mgbayh7gpa mydomain.xn--mgbbh1a71e mydomain.xn--mgbc0a9azcg mydomain.xn--mgberp4a5d4ar mydomain.xn--mgbx4cd0ab mydomain.xn--ngbc5azd mydomain.xn--nqv7f mydomain.xn--nqv7fs00ema mydomain.xn--o3cw4h mydomain.xn--ogbpf8fl mydomain.xn--p1ai mydomain.xn--pgbs0dh mydomain.xn--q9jyb4c mydomain.xn--rhqv96g mydomain.xn--s9brj9c mydomain.xn--ses554g mydomain.xn--unup4y mydomain.xn--wgbh1c mydomain.xn--wgbl6a mydomain.xn--xkc2al3hye2a mydomain.xn--xkc2dl3a5ee0h mydomain.xn--yfro4i67o mydomain.xn--ygbi2ammx mydomain.xn--zfr164b mydomain.xxx mydomain.xyz mydomain.ye mydomain.yokohama mydomain.yt mydomain.za mydomain.zm mydomain.zone mydomain.zw

  Redirect / https://www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```